# Advanced image scaling in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to include many images of unknown origin in a report. I have no idea what the images might be: portrait or landscape fotos, large or small, or even something with an atypical shape, like a 400x80 logo.

I'd like to scale down images with the following rule: proportionally downscale until the larger side is 200. And resulting image shouldn't take more space than needed (i.e. 1000x600 should be downscaled to 200x120, *not* to 200x200), so that there are no unneeded blank margins around non-square images.

Is what I need possible with JasperReports?

**EDIT:**

To clarify: "real size" mode is *almost* what I need.  However, I don't see a way to limit height of resulting image. As a result, if the image I want to print is a portrait foto (or has even larger height compared to width), generated PDF looks ugly; in this case I would prefer to somehow downscale it to a smaller width.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem of resizing images of various sizes to a fixed size with "RetainShape" by writing an ImageResizer, based on the idea of the ImageTransformer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/8957103 , using https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr for scaling the image.